# Problema ao ordenar query do elasticsearch/django

Tags: django, elasticsearch

Eu tenho esse modelo do Django:

```
class Profile(User):

rg = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True,blank=True)
cpf = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, null=True)
about = models.TextField(_('about'),max_length = 10000, null=True, blank=True)
knowledge = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategory, related_name="profile_knowledge")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('profile')
    verbose_name_plural = _('profiles')
    db_table = 'pd_profile'
    permissions = (
        ("view_all_users", "Can view user details"),
        ("edit_all_users", "Can edit user details"),
        ("search_profile", "Can search talents"),
        ("user_config", "Can access user config page "),
        ("add_users_permissions", "Can add global permissions to user"),
        ("export_user_data", _("Can export users data")),
    )

def __str__(self):
    return self.full_name
```

E eu quero fazer uma query pelos Perfis dessa maneira:

```
query = SearchQuerySet().all().models(Profile)
t = query.filter(content=data.get('value'))
if not t:
    suggestion = query.spelling_suggestion(data.get('value'))
    t = query.filter(content=suggestion)
query = t
query = query.order_by("full_name")
```

Meu problema é que não retorna em ordem alfabética de jeito nenhum.. To fazendo algo errado? Valeu!

django-haystack==2.5.0 djangorestframework==3.3.2 elasticsearch==1.5.2

Comment: Olá Lucas aproveito para dar as boas vindas ao StackOverflow, dá uma olhada ao código de conduta, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct.

Comment: Quanto à tua questão, aproveita e coloca o resultado (alguns resultados) e o que estás à espera que retorne.

Answer (score 1):

Se alguém teve esse mesmo problema o que faltava era adicionar o campo no `search_indexes.py` da seguinte forma:

```
full_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='full_name', indexed=False, stored=True)
```

Feito isso, dei um `rebuild_index` e funcionou perfeitamente.